# Wrapper box for TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, diagrams, boxes

I am trying to wrap a tikzpicture node inside a box, so that I can refer to this "bounding box" from inside the picture for positioning the nodes relative to that box. I am looking for a command similar to the following one (in this example only "My Node B" is placed on top of the current page):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test Frame}
    \makebox[\textwidth]{  % %%% any alternative?
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw (current bounding box.north) node (__node_ref)
            [anchor=north,fill=gray]
        {My node A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw (current page.north) node (__node_ref)
            [anchor=north,fill=gray]
        {My node B};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This way, I can resize the external box and keep the relative position of the nodes of the tikzpicture intact. I tried using \makebox, \framebox and \pfgbox (the latter from inside the {tikzpicture}), but none of them worked.

I know that normally "current bounding box" might work, but I am doing this within Beamer+XeLaTeX and I can only access to the node "current page", so that I have to use "shift" for centering the nodes again.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `current bounding box` doesn't work because you've added the `overlay` option to the first node, which produces a bounding box of "zero dimension". Does your first `tikzpicture` have to be absolutely positioned?

Comment: I would like to add it inside a "box" (like in the example) and let beamer choose the position for the box in accordance with the current slide layout. I would like to specify the width and height of the box, but as I said before, I would also like beamer to position the box automatically.

Comment: @Ricardo: Then you can remove the `overlay` option and just use the `current bounding box` of the node in the first picture.

Comment: @Ricardo Solved the comment of Herr K the question? If yes you or HerrK could write an answer, which could be [accepted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments

Comment: Yes, the question has been answered but Herr K. has not written the answer in the proper way... that is why I did not close the question.